# Canvas App redirects to website

Tags: connected-apps, canvas

I have a canvas app, now I want to show the canvas app inside a Lightning component. And that Lightning component is to be accessed via a custom tab.
Below is my code:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable" access="global">
<div class="canvas-container">
    <force:canvasApp developerName="GoalQuest"/>
</div>
```

The issue with this is that when I click on the tab the lightning component is loaded and I expect that website (which we have given inside canvas app as Canvas App URL) should be seen inside the lightning component (like we see in iFrame) but this is actually redirecting to the website itself. Any idea what could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say "but this is actually redirecting to the website itself"? If you mean the browser is redirecting your entire tab outside of salesforce.com, the 3rd party website must be doing that redirect by setting window.top.location.

You are correct that the iframe should display the URL you've configured as the Canvas App URL.